# image got 5px extra, display:block not working

Tags: css, image

Why is there some extra white space between the images? shouldn't they be like glued together?
jsfiddle:`http://jsfiddle.net/VS4r7/`
I have looked for other answers here, most of them say that i just shoud add `display:block` but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: That's whitespace between the elements.

Comment: You remember that warning you got when you posted a link to jsFiddle in your question without code? Yeah...that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the whitespace between elements, change your div `inline-block` to `table-cell`

```
div {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: That's working! but... why is there whitespace to begin with..? (google it right now)

Comment: default space between elements. If that works for you, please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When you're inside any kind of inline element, whitespaces in your source html are considered part of the inline content, taking some amount of pixels.
Now, if you just need 3 images in a row, first thing remove the div wrapping any image, you don't need it. After that, you have two options:

1) remove any particular `display` directive from both div and img, and write the 3 img tags without whitespaces in between: Example:

```
<img src="#" /><img src="#" /><img src="#" />
```

with css:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}

img {

    height:100px;
    width:100px;

}
```

2) have img tags be treated as left-floated blocks, so you can ignore the whitespaces problem. Example:

```
<img src="#" />
<img src="#" />
<img src="#" />
```

With css:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}

img {
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

Note: if you use floated blocks inside a parent div, remember that you can have issues with parent div's size, unless you add an empty div after the imgs OR add `overflow:hidden` css on parent div.